# Batch Script - create an .XML file - name based on every .DWG file in folder

Tags: xml, batch-file

I'd like to create a Batch file that would search a folder and create .XML files based on the .DWG file names.  It would also add the file name to (2) difference locations within the .XML (see below).

Process:

1. A folder contains (100) .DWG files numbered A1.dwg ~ A100.dwg
2. The Batch file would find these file names and create the corresponding .XML file
3. Within the .XML file (2) lines would be edited based on the file name

XML Contents for file "A26":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<File Name="A26"><Version>1</Version><Description>A26</Description><Region><Cell Level="1" Division="1"/><Cell Level="1" Division="1"/></Region></File>
```

XML Contents for file "A42":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<File Name="A42"><Version>1</Version><Description>A42</Description><Region><Cell Level="2" Division="1"/><Cell Level="2" Division="1"/></Region></File>
```

XML Contents for file "A74":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<File Name="A74"><Version>1</Version><Description>A74</Description><Region><Cell Level="3" Division="1"/><Cell Level="3" Division="1"/></Region></File>
```

I was able to put together the following based on another inquiry, however, it's not working for me... anything you can offer would be much appreciated.

BTW, `"targetdir=C:\USC VILLAGE"` is the location I'm trying to output these files, but I'd like to be able to edit this path and create these files anywhere if possible.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "targetdir=C:\USC VILLAGE"
SET /a filecount=0
SET "and_subdirs="
:again
PUSHD "%targetdir%"
FOR %and_subdirs% %%a IN (
  "*.dwg"
 ) DO (
  SET /a filecount+=1
  >"%%~dpna.xml" (
   ECHO(^<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   ECHO(         <File Name="%%~na">
   ECHO(         <Version>1</Version>
   ECHO(         <Description>%%~nxa"</Description>
   ECHO(         </File^>
  )
  )
  )
)
popd
IF NOT DEFINED and_subdirs IF %filecount%==0 SET "and_subdirs=/r"& GOTO again
ECHO(%filecount% files found
IF DEFINED and_subdirs ECHO(Subdirectories were scanned

GOTO :EOF
```

Thanks,
DOrtega

Comment: Where the `<Cell Level="3" Division="1"/>` comes from? And why doubled in all your _XML Contents_ description?

Comment: Does it have to be batch, or is for example `perl` (which will work on Windows) an option? Reason I ask - XML is a lot more complicated than it seems, and using a proper parser helps MASSIVELY.

Comment: @JosefZ—I'll have to confirm the Cell Level and Division and whether or not they are duplicates. These are directly related to AutoCAD.  This bit of information tells AutoCAD what level the file is associated to (ex. level 3), and division (ex. area 4)

Comment: @JosefZ—I confirmed the <Cell Level="3" Division="1"/> is duplicated.  I'm not sure why, but again, it's an AutoCAD thing.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not quite what you ask for, but I'm going to offer it anyway. It's perl, rather than batch because:

- Perl will run on Windows too.
- Perl handles XML a lot better than batch ever can.

To get this to run 'from scratch you would need to:

- Install perl (from somewhere like: http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/downloads )
- install `XML::Twig` - if you're running Activeperl via `ppm install XML-Twig`.

I'm unclear how you figured out cell level and division, so have used placeholder values. It should be easy to modify this accordingly.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;
use File::Find;

#read search and output dirs from command line, but use defaults if not present. 
my ( $search_dir, $output_dir ) = @_;
$search_dir = 'C:\\temp\\dwg' unless defined $search_dir;
$output_dir = 'C:\\temp'      unless defined $output_dir;

sub process_file {
    return unless m/\.dwg$/;
    print "Processing $File::Find::name\n";
    my $base_name = $_;
    #extract the 'A24' bit. 
    $base_name =~ s#\.dwg$##gi;  
    print "Using $base_name\n";

    #start assembling XML:
    my $xml = XML::Twig->new( pretty_print => 'indented' );

    #create a 'File' roote element.
    $xml->set_root(
        XML::Twig::Elt->new( 'File', { "Name", $File::Find::name } ) );

    #insert Version and description into root element.
    $xml->root->insert_new_elt( 'Version',     1 );
    $xml->root->insert_new_elt( 'Description', $base_name );

    #create a region element, with subelements 'Cell'
    my $region = $xml->root->insert_new_elt( 'last_child', 'Region' );
    $region->insert_new_elt(
        'Cell',
        {   'Level'    => 1,
            'Division' => 1,
        }
    );
    $xml->print;

    open( my $output_file, ">", "$output_dir/$base_name.xml" ) or warn $!;
    print {$output_file} $xml->sprint;
    close($output_file);
}


find( \&process_file, $search_dir );
```

Comment: —the Batch is being used to create the XMLs only because it doesn't take an additional program to install and/or learn for additional team members.  I appreciate the help with this and will look into it further, however, I'd like to stick to Batch files for the time being.

Comment: that's fair enough. I will warn you though - you're making a rod for your own backs. XML is a complex construct, and parsing it isn't trivial. I won't way it -can't- be done in batch, but it's very very easy to trip over the very strict data format.

Answer (score 0):

Your script could work if you will [escape](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) all `<` (less than) and `>` (greater than) characters with `^` Escape character properly *within* all `echo` commands  (not in the `>"%%~dpna.xml" (` line) as follows:

```
  >"%%~dpna.xml" (
    ECHO(^<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?^>
    ECHO(^<File Name="%%~na"^>
    ECHO(    ^<Version^>1^</Version^>
    ECHO(    ^<Description^>%%~nxa^</Description^>
    ECHO(^</File^>
   )
```

However, **I doubt the output file could be forced to** `UTF-8` **encoding** with CLI batch (read more in [this `CHCP` article](http://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html) at least).

I'd follow Sobrique's recommendation: switch to another, `xml` properly handling tool...